# How can I mock a service class inside a Laravel Job?

Tags: laravel, testing, service, mocking, laravel-service-container

I want to mock a service who call a third party, but I can't figure it out.

I have a controller method who has a service injected on it and do stuff:

```php
public function store(Request $request, MyService $myService)
{
    $data = $request->validated();

    $myService->create($data, $request->user());

    return response()->json();
}
```

In this service, I call a job to do other stuffs:

```php
MyJob::dispatch($manager);
```

My job is built like this:

```php
public function __construct(private Manager $manager)
{
}

public function handle()
{
    // THE SERVICE I WANT TO MOCK
    $this->managementService = resolve(ManagementService::class, ['manager_id' => $this->manager->id]);
    $this->doStuff();
}

private function doStuff() {
    $this->managementService->startManagement();
}
```

In ManagementService I want to mock the function callApi:

```php
public function startManagement()
{
    $data = $this->callApi('/thirdparty/call');

    return $data;
}
```

SO, in my test I try to mock the ManagementService and call my route who do all these things

```php
$this->mock(ManagementService::class, function ($mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('callApi')->andReturn('none');
});

$response = $this->actingAs(User::factory()->create())->post('/myroute', [
    'manager_id' => 4,
]);
```

But it seems this mock is never used, it's still going into the "normal" Management Service, because when I dump $data in the startManagement method when I launch tests, it's not returning 'none'.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What I would do is just mock the job. You can mock the calls to it and then assert if the job was called/triggered with the desired/expected input. Then in a unit test, you test the job specifically. Read [this part](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#queue-fake)

Comment: I still have a service in my job whatever if I unit test the job. Problem is the same, I don't have my service mocked

Answer (score 1):

The code that you post is not very clear but if i understand correctly you like to mock a [hard dependency](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/mocking_hard_dependencies.html) thats why your mock never called because you never register it.

Just add the string `overload` before the class name in the mock method.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by injecting my service directly in the job

```php
MyJob::dispatch($manager, resolve(ManagementService::class,  ['manager_id' => $this->manager->id]));
```

And inside the service instance it via constructor instead of in the handle

```php
public function __construct(public Manager $manager, ManagementService $managementService)
{
    $this->managementService = $managementService;
}
```

Then in my test, my mock is instancied like this:

```php
$mock = Mockery::mock(ManagementService::class);
        $mock->shouldReceive('callApi')
             ->once()
             ->andReturn('none');
```

Thanks to all